# How to self left join root using JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1

I am trying to use multiple left joins on the same table to transpose the counting of tickets by severity into columns.
So I wonder if it is possible to write the following SQL Query as JPA CriteriaQuery:

```
select c.name, count(t) total, count(t0.id) as sev0, count(t1.id) as sev1, count(t2.id) as sev2
from tickets t
left join tickets t0 on t.id = t0.id and t0.severity = 0
left join tickets t1 on t.id = t1.id and t1.severity = 1
left join tickets t2 on t.id = t2.id and t2.severity = 2
inner join customers c on t.customer = c.id
group by c.name
order by c.name;
```

While the expected output would be something like this:

```
customer_name                    total  sev0  sev1  sev2
b1873f8bdcd4847e05ec942da3273bc0    1    1     0     0  
bc757dead99fb9658b1e42877f1febfb    20   3     5     12 
52793217b1f42c69e93df8eaf86f8db4    10   0     4     6
```

I've tried using multiple roots which hibernate turned into a cross join but then it did not work for me.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CustomerDTO> query = cb.createQuery(CustomerDTO.class);
Root<Ticket> tickets = query.from(Tickets.class);
Root<Ticket> sev0 = query.from(Ticket.class);
Root<Ticket> sev1 = query.from(Ticket.class);
Root<Ticket> sev2 = query.from(Ticket.class);
Join<Customer, Tickets> customer = query.join("customer_id");

Predicate sev0Condition = cb.and(cb.equal(tickets.get("id"), sev0.get("id")), cb.equal(sev0.get("severity"), cb.literal(0));
Predicate sev1Condition = cb.and(cb.equal(tickets.get("id"), sev1.get("id")), cb.equal(sev1.get("severity"), cb.literal(1));
Predicate sev2Condition = cb.and(cb.equal(tickets.get("id"), sev2.get("id")), cb.equal(sev2.get("severity"), cb.literal(2));

query.select(cb.construct(CustomerDTO.class, customer, cb.count(tickets.get("id"), cb.count(sev0.get("id"), cb.count(sev1.get("id"), cb.count(sev2.get("id")));
query.where(sev0Condition, sev1Condition, sev2Condition);
query.groupBy(customer);

List<CustomerDTO> customerList = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to avoid self joins. This query could easily be formulated to use no self joins like this:

```
select c.name, count(*) total, count(case when t.severity = 0 then 1 else null end) as sev0, count(case when t.severity = 1 then 1 else null end) as sev1, count(case when t.severity = 2 then 1 else null end) as sev2
from tickets t
inner join customers c on t.customer = c.id
group by c.name
order by c.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I guess by the time you've posted it I'd already solved this by using subselects instead of self joins. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one because it looks nicer and probably performs better than what I came with up as a solution.

thanks again!